# ¿Cómo añadir datos a un <input type=“text”> con jquery

Tags: jquery

La pregunta es la siguiente como puedo cambiar el valor de uno de los inputs del formulario antes de enviar todo el contenido de el formulario ?

Quiero pasar como argumento todo el contenido del formulario a la función validateForms() pero justo antes de enviárselo quiero cambiar el valor de un input

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script>
 
 
var form = $('#italia-form' > "#italia_pass").val('514') ;
  validateForms(form, {handleMsg: false});
 
  </script>
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="italia-form">
     
  <fieldset>
<input type="text" id="user_italia"  placeholder="Usuario" required disabled></input>
 <input type="password" id="italia_pass" name="italia_pass" placeholder="Contraseña" required disabled>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: la respuesta de Damian es la correcta, en tu caso si quieres usar los 2 ids es lo siguiente:
$('#italia-form>#italia_pass').val('514');

Answer (score 2):

Con el ID:

```
$("#idElemento").val("valor");
```

Con la Clase:

```
$(".claseElemento").val("valor");
```

A todos las etiquetas p por ejemplo:

```
$("p").val("valor");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
jQuery("#idCampo").val("valor a asignar")
```

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.